# Bootstrap dropdown does not close when click on bootstrap tab contents

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using both of the bootstrap drop downs and tabs. Everything works fine and drop down gets close when I click anywhere on the page except bootstrap tabs. Dropdowns does not close when I click on bootstrap tabs(its name or tab contents). This is probably due to z-index. I could not find its solution and I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Aisha

Comment: Some code would help, even a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715579/twitter-bootstrap-close-collapsible-menu-when-dropdown-menu-is-open/19716863#19716863 - Might be helpful to you.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/19715579/ is not helpful for me. I am not using collapsible plugin.

Comment: @aishazafar an example would be helpful then.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it's hard to tell what's happening, but you could try to hack it with jquery:

```
$('.your_tab_class').on('click', function(){
          $("body").click();
});
```

With this code, when you click in content with the class `.your_tab_class` the jquery clicks on body, so If you say that if you click on body it closes the dropdown, it should close this way.
Hope this helps